# How do I send data by mail in PHP with HTML (a link) and get that data back to my server after recipient has clicked on the link

Tags: php, html, email

I am sending a mail to multiple recipients and I want to get the data from that when I get it back in my server.

What I want to do is keep the token in the form sent in the link so that when the recipient opens his/her mail and clicks on the link the data is passed to my server.

I'm thinking of solving this by sending the recipients each their own token by mail and then when the recipient opens their mail they can click on the link. I want to attach the data from the token in a form.

```
<form action="href='http://localhost/poll/'" method="post" >

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="token">
    <input type="submit" name="poll" value="Take Poll">

</form>
```

Other way i'm thinking of solving this is by sending a complete link and then when the recipient clicks on the link it can go back to the server and then I would be able to break down the link to only get the token. How would I go about doing this?

```
<a href="http://localhost/poll/">Poll to Answer</a>
```

What I want is to be able to get the token back to my server to give the recipient his/her poll.

Right now I am sending it directly to my localhost for testing purposes. The path exists in my local server.

this is my mail code to send to the recipients:

```
<?php

// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', ';
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Quick Poll';
$token = "nfjdsfEXAMPLEkajsdnlkaj";
$link = "www.example.com/polls/";
$linkToken = $link.$token;



// message
$message = $linkToken;

$message = '

            <form action="href='http://localhost/poll/'" method="post" >


                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="token">
                <input type="submit" name="poll" value="Take Poll">

            </form>

            ';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: me <myMail@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myMailArchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: myMailCheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: don't put a form in an email the email client wont submit it, send a simple href link

Comment: How do I get the token from the link then? to see who was the one that clicked on the link. www.example.com/fdaEXAMPLEadf

Comment: @Fred -ii- your raining on my parade bro.

Comment: @Dagon OP didn't bring the right balloons. They used the same ones.

Answer (score 1):

in the email you add a href link:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?token=fdaEXAMPLEadf`

on index.php

token is in `$_GET['token']`

Comment: so when i get back the link in my server i add `$_GET['token']` which I should be able to get from `?token=fdaEXAMPLEadf` is that what you are telling me?

Comment: `echo $_GET['token'];` in index.php will return `fdaEXAMPLEadf`

Comment: @Dagon Strangely enough, I've built one of these *from the ground up* today. Took me a while to get it all right. Too bad I can't "share" it. That would be "giving it away".  Complete with email, password reset and passphrase verification. I'm sure I could have easily "Google'd" it, but I like building stuff myself. Learning how to do so, sticks better to the palette, just like peanut butter.

Comment: yhea i have several, i use to write a newsletter SAAS

Comment: @Dagon yes, I remember you telling me that once.